# Error when creating downloadable product

Tags: magento-1, downloadable, upload

When i try to create a downloadable product,i face the below issue when trying to upload the music file(<2mb).I'm new to magento.Someone pls help..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini to your desired quantity